# Debugging in Monodevelop on OSX not quite working

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop, immediate-window

Hey guys, just installed on my Mac Snow Leopard OSX:

Mono 2.6 and Monodevelop 2.2

I've created a simple C# Console App:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

When I start to type "Console" intellisense works perfectly.

When I run the app in Debug mode, breakpoints hit as expected.

However, while debugging with breakpoints, if I hover over "Console" it says "Unknown Identifier"

When I try and use the immediate window, nothing works. Anything I type just says "Unknown Identifier."

Anyone know what's going on?

cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and compiling with the -debug flag on:

```
public static int Main (string[] args) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!"); 
    Console.Read(); 
    return 0; // Place breakpoint here
}
```

If that works then try this:

```
public static void Main (string[] args) 
{ 
    int dummy;
    Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!"); // Place breakpoint here
    Console.Read(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks fupsduck, it'll try that out and get back to you. cheers!

Comment: did you try compiling with the -debug flag on?

Comment: hmm... I think so. I clicked on the debug button, not the run button. I'll try tonight as my Mac's at home. cheers dude

Comment: if it works with breakpoint on return 0, then try on Console.Read(). If that works but not when on Console.WriteLine() add int dummy; to top of file to start break on Console.WriteLine().

Answer (score 3):

Please [file a bug report](http://monodevelop.com/Developers#Reporting_Bugs).

Comment: is this a known bug? I don't know if it is a bug, might be something I've done...? Does anyone know what I'm talking about? I'm totally new to Mono...?

Comment: It's know to be an issue with types that have not yet been loaded by the debuggee. Is your breakpoint before the program calls Console?

Comment: is there a way to explicitly load types into the debugger...?

Comment: Not yet, no. This isn't something we can fix in MonoDevelop either; it needs to be fixed in the debugger in the Mono runtime.

Comment: I dug a bit deeper and filed a bug for you: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=570855

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I can reproduce exactly what you're describing (Mac OS X, same versions, similar Hello World code, using a breakpoint on the first code line). However, as soon as I "Step Over" to the next line, the popup shows up correctly for "Console". As such, this behavior seems acceptable (at least to me).

Comment: hmm... thanks fmr, that's good to know. My Mac's at home, but as soon as I get in tonight I'll give it another look. Could you tell me if you can also use the Immediate window ok? cheers!

Comment: yes, same behavior for Immediate window. As soon as "Step Over" is performed, you can evaluate "Console.CapsLock" for example.

Comment: Like I said in the comments to my answer, it's know to be an issue that MD is currently only able to access types after they've been loaded by the debuggee.